# wordpress contact form7, one form redirect to multiple thank you page based on is_page

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am looking for a solution on wordpress contact form7.
    either a plugin or in PHP code.
    I am not looking for JavaScript solution. as I have already found JavaScript solution. Again: I am looking for either **plugin** or **PHP code**.
    I want to use one form (CF7) and it will redirect to multiple thank you pages based on from which page the form submitted. 
Below example code.

```
if is_page(1){
  contact-form will go to thank-you-page-1
} else if is_page(2) {
  contact-form will go to thank-you-page-2
}
```

Comment: you already found solution in javascript  then why again you want in php or plugin? you can redirect to multiple thankyou page in javascript also

Comment: you already found solution in javascript then why again you want in php or plugin? for plugin check this link
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-success-page-redirects/  or  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/

Comment: javascript can control, disable from front end. so I need this in serverside php language so that the code must execute. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this hook

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {

    // Run code after the email has been sent
$wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
 $wpccfid=$wpcf->id;

    // if you wanna check the ID of the Form $wpcf->id
     if ( '34' == $wpccfid ) { // Change 123 to the ID of the form 

         //you can use also if(is_page()){} condition 

    //redirect to url
    wp_redirect('url of thank you page');
     exit();

     }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if that actually works with the default AJAX form submission …

Comment: I will check this and put my feedback...thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (is_page(array(1))) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
            location = 'https://page-link-1.com/';
        }, false );
    </script>
<?php } else if ( is_page(array(2))) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
            location = 'https://page-link-2.com/';
        }, false );
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```